# Magento 2 get catalog rule product details in final_price.phtml

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2, phtml, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I will try keep simple and short.

e.g I have set a rule in catalogrule table  and I am interested in 2 fields value:

```
simple_action: by_percent  
discount_amount: 40.0000
```

and in  `catalogrule_product` table there are 2 field that I am interested they are:

```
action_operator: by_percent
action_amount: 40.0000
```

**How do one get `action_operator` and `action_amount` values in `final_price.phtml` ?**

Comment: @Nikunj Vadariya Any ideas ? I appreciate.

Comment: I hope my answer will help with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some code related to your question:

**Path:**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule.php

Check function `public function calcProductPriceRule(Product $product, $price)`

```
$rulesData = $this->_getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);

$ruleData['action_operator'];
$ruleData['action_amount'];
```